# Why are these types not the same?

Tags: c++, type-traits, typeid, typeinfo

Why do T1 and T2 have the same typeid but are not the same type? (The output is `1 0`)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  using T1 = decltype("A");
  using T2 = const char[2];
  std::cout << (typeid(T1) == typeid(T2)) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::is_same_v<T1,T2> << "\n";
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8M4G1T61q

Comment: By the way, on recent compilers std::source_location::current().function_name() can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literal like `"A"` is [lvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category), as the effect [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) leads to lvalue-reference, so `T1` would be `const char (&)[2]`.

> if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields `T&`;

`T2` is `const char[2]`, and [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) on `T1` will give the result referring to the referenced type, i.e., `const char[2]`, that's why `typeid(T1) == typeid(T2)` is `true`, but `std::is_same_v<T1,T2>` is `false`.

> If type is a reference type, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing `the cv-unqualified version (since C++11)` of the referenced type.

Answer (score 5):

`T1` has type `const char(&)[2]`. A reference is an alias of `const char[2]` and has the same `typeid`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  using T1 = decltype("A");
  using T2 = const char[2];
  using T3 = T2&;
  std::cout << (typeid(T1) == typeid(T2)) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::is_same_v<T1,T3> << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
1
1
```

Comment: Is it common to put `(&)` in parens? Is it incorrect to omit those?

Comment: What do you mean? You can `typedef char T2[2];` or `typedef char (&T1)[2];`. The type `T1` is the reference `T2&`.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's where the parens come from. It's like function pointer syntax

Comment: @Thomas It is the operator precedence. If you omit parens, you define an array of references to chars instead of a reference to an array of chars.

Comment: Thanks. It just looks strange, since parens around basically nothing can typically be omitted. Like `(1)` is identical to `1`. But we need to consider the invisible name inside the parens here.